# cookie delete problem

Tags: php, cookies

I have two simple functions to set and clear cookie.

```
 private function _setCookie($value = null) {
    $value = $value === null ? $this->getRandomId() : $value;
    setcookie($this->getName(), $value, time()+10800, '/');
}

private function _clearCookie() {                       
    setcookie($this->getName(), '', time()-10800, '/');                
}
```

There is a page when accessed starts session and create a cookie as desired. When redirect call happens from different server to my page , delete cookie function calls internally above _clearCookie funtion.I checked setcookie returns true and I also tried to unset cookie in same method but cookie is still available when I reload page. I still can find that cookie in browser as well as firebug and print_r($_COOKIE)

Also I changed expire time to time()-(3600*24) as mentioned is some others threads but no change in my case. What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure you're not sending data before setting cookies, else the headers will be ignored.

Comment: I have verified and there is no data sending before cookie delte call

Comment: Looking around set it for way back:
setcookie("cookiename","",mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1990), "/");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so when I mentioned 'redirect call happens from different server to my page' I was trying to mention it as back channel call. And being a back channel call, browser cookies were not getting identified I suppose and that is the main reason even if setcookie returns me true, actual cookie deletion from browser would never happen in such cases.